# XOR Operator in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm new in implementing Eigen Library in VS C++ 2010.
My problem is that I can't find the operator XOR to make it in my matrix. I use ^ to make my XOR operations C++ and it does work but in Eigen it doesn't works. Can anyone tell me if there's an XOR Operator for Eigen ? I all ready read the documentation but I can't find it. Heres the code that I'm working on :

```
m(0,1) = 1;
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
       m(i + 1,j + 1) = m(i,j) ^ m(i, j + 2);
       cout << m(i,j) << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Define "doesn't work." Is the matrix using an integer type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your question, as very important bits of your code are missing (the declaration of m). Let's try to give an answer under different assumptions:

1) The snipped you provided is the code you want but it's not working as intended:

In case you have declared `m` as

```
Eigen::Matrix<int,9,9> m;
```

The code should work. Something like `Eigen::Matrix<float,9,9>` would not work, since the `^` operator is not defined on float types in c++. `Eigen::MatrixXf` would be a dynamic version of your matrix, and result in the same error. You don't provide what the error is, so it could also be something completely different, e.g. wrong dimensioning of `m`

2) The snippet you provided is working for you, and you seek to replicate the same functionality with built-in eigen operators:

There is no `^` operator defined on Eigen types in the [reference](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/QuickRefPage.html#QuickRef_Coeffwise). But again, the operator in your snipped is not on Eigen types, as the return value of of your access operation `m(i,j)` is a ValueType reference to whatever type you used to declare `m` with.